# IIS FTP 8.5 DataChannel timeout with a linux client

Tags: linux, iis, ftp

I've got a strange situation. Hope someone can help. I've got two independent IIS FTP servers.

1. IIS 7.5 runs as standalone VM
2. IIS 8.5 runs on a windows server 2012 R2 VM

When I connect to these ftp servers using FileZilla client (or the pftp client on ubuntu), both work as expected, really well. Passive mode, no problem.

When one of my customer's linux client is connecting, it works great on the IIS 7.5, but it does not work on the IIS 8.5

It stops after the PASV command with a timeout. The linux client is running a custom app on fedora which has FTP functionality embedded in it.

For authentication i'm using IIS Manager Users.

Does anyone have an idea of what this could be? Or how to troubleshoot this?? I can test, and see everything working, except when the clients processes are entering the scene!

Comment: A packet capture from working and non working connections from the same client host but different software might help, especially since there is a "custom app ... which has FTP functionality embedded in it" involved which might have a specific implementation causing the problems. Please check that you can do FTP transfers outside of the custom app from the fedora host and then provide packet captures were one might see the different behaviors.

Comment: Steffen thanks for your feedback. The issue has given me many gray hairs, but the solution is found ... the customer admin told me there was some issue with the proxy server the customer app was running behind. After he made a change, the ftp session were all flawless.